# VSC no muestra el contenido de archivos pickle en binario

Tags: python, vscode

He estado aprendiendo sobre el manejo de ficheros:

```
import pickle
from io import open

class Pelicula:

    # Constructor de clase
    def __init__(self, titulo, duracion, lanzamiento):
        self.titulo = titulo
        self.duracion = duracion
        self.lanzamiento = lanzamiento
        print('Se ha creado la película:',self.titulo)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} ({})'.format(self.titulo, self.lanzamiento)


class Catalogo:

    peliculas = []

    # Constructor de clase
    def __init__(self):
        self.cargar()

    def agregar(self,p):
        self.peliculas.append(p)
        self.guardar()

    def mostrar(self):
        if len(self.peliculas) == 0:
            print("El catálogo está vacío")
            return
        for p in self.peliculas:
            print(p)

    def cargar(self):
        fichero = open('catalogo.pckl', 'ab+')
        fichero.seek(0)
        try:
            self.peliculas = pickle.load(fichero)
        except:
            print("El fichero está vacío")
        finally:
            fichero.close()
            print("Se han cargado {} películas".format(len(self.peliculas)))

    def guardar(self):
        fichero = open('catalogo.pckl', 'wb')
        pickle.dump(self.peliculas, fichero)
        fichero.close()

    #Destructor
    def __del__(self):
        self.guardar()
        print("se ha guardado")


c = Catalogo()

c.agregar(Pelicula("El Padrino", 175, 1972))
c.agregar(Pelicula("El Padrino: 2", 202, 1974))

c = Catalogo()

c.agregar(Pelicula("Pelicula", 100, 1974))

c = Catalogo()

c.mostrar()
```

y cuando quiero abrir en binario los archivos que creo desde Visual Studio Code o me salen algo así:�]q o esta vacío, lo cual no me pasa cuando los creo en Jupyter y los abro con Sublime que sales asi: 8003 5d71 0028 4b01 4b02 4b03 4b04 4b05
652e. 
Es algo del programa? Debo instalar alguna extension?

Un saludo!

Comment: No entiendo muy bien...para que quieres abrir los ficheros binarios en un editor de texto?

Comment: Los archivos pickle contienen bytes arbitrarios, quizás no decodificables como caracteres. Se ve que Sublime detecta que el fichero no es "legible" y elige mostrarte su representación hexadecimal, mientras que VS Code simplemente te muestra los bytes como "basura" al intentar decodificarlso como caracteres. Prueba la extensión [hexdump](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=slevesque.vscode-hexdump) de VSCode